# Laravel dynamic routing with interface

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have an app which requires different `HomeController`depending on subdomain I'm using. So for example `domain.mydomain.com/news` should point to one controller and `mydomain.com/news` to other.

Is there any way to use interfaces in routes since now I'm getting an error that my interface is not instantiable:

```
Route::controller('home', 'RouterInterface', [
    'getIndex' => 'home.index'
]);
```

Even if this somehow worked, I don't know where would I even inject concrete classes in order for this to pull adequate method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'domain.mydomain.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/news', function()
    {
        return 'My sub domain';
    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'mydomain.com'], function()
{
    Route::any('/news', function()
    {
        return 'My main domain';
    });
});
```